# Need help on this closest point optimisation problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am getting stuck on this optimisation problem and I would be grateful if anyone could help me solve it.

> Submarines are located at $(2,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Choose the slope $m$ so the line $y = mx$ goes between the submarines but stays as far as possible from the nearest one.

Please do not give away the answer but point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $m$, you can find the point on $y = mx$ that is nearest to $(2,0)$  by solving
\begin{align}
y &= mx \\
y-0 &= -\frac{1}{m}(x-2)
\end{align}
for $(x,y)$, yielding $(x_1,y_1)$.
Similarly, you can find the point on $y = mx$ that is nearest to $(1,1)$ by solving
\begin{align}
y &= mx \\
y-1 &= -\frac{1}{m}(x-1)
\end{align}
for $(x,y)$, yielding $(x_2,y_2)$.
Let these two nearest distances be
\begin{align}
d_1(m) &= \sqrt{(2-x_1)^2+(0-y_1)^2} \\
d_2(m) &= \sqrt{(1-x_2)^2+(1-y_2)^2}
\end{align}
Now let $f(m)=\min(d_1(m),d_2(m))$ be the distance from the line $y=mx$ to the nearer submarine.  You want to maximize $f(m)$ subject to $0 \le m \le 1$.  Hint: this maximum will occur where $d_1(m)=d_2(m)$.

Drag the slider for $m$ here to see a graphical representation:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/snnpapyfln

Comment: I solved the first and second set of equations and got something like this:
$$x = \frac{2}{m^2 + 1}$$ and
$$x = \frac{m + 1}{m^2 + 1}$$
So what do I do now?

Comment: Yes, those are correct.  Now solve for $y$ in each case, and then express the two distances as functions of $m$.

Comment: So find equations for y and express them in terms of $f(m) = y_1 + y_2$
Thank you

Comment: Not quite.  Instead $f(m)=\min(d_1(m),d_2(m))$, where $d_1(m)$ is the distance from $(2,0)$ to $(x_1,y_1)$ and $d_2(m)$ is the distance from $(1,1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: So I minimise $d_1(m)$ and $d_2(m)$ and them maximise $f(m)$?
Also could you explain why we need to do min($d_1(m), d_2(m)$)
Thank you for helping me

Comment: No, you maximize the minimum.  "as far as possible" means maximize, and "from the nearest one" means the $\min$.  This is called a "maximin" problem.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%27s_maximin_model#Deterministic_models

Comment: So how exactly would I do $min(d_1(m), d_2(m))$? Sorry I have never heard of Walds maximin model. Thank you for showing me this.

Comment: $\min(a,b)$ means compute $a$ and $b$ and take the smaller of the two.

Comment: So I take the smaller of the $d_1(m)$ and $d_2(m)$ and maximise that? Thank you for helping me out

Comment: Glad to help.  Make sure you see my updated answer with more details, a hint, and a link to an interactive graphical representation.

Comment: I have, it was very helpful.
Just to make sure, how do we know which of $d_1$ and $d_2$ is smaller

Comment: Which one of $d_1(m)$ and $d_2(m)$ is smaller depends on $m$, and there is a unique value of $m \in [0,1]$ where they are equal.